# Maven example of annotation preprocessing and generation of classes in same compile process?

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, preprocessor

Does anyone have a clean example of a maven project preprocessing class annotations at compile time with subsequent generation of classes to be compiled in the same compilation process?

Does anyone have a step-by-step procedure to implement such a project?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After navigating a lot in existing documentation on the net, I came up with the following:

**What needs to be clarified:**

- In order to process annotations on a given project P, you first need an annotation processor compiled in a separate library S. P should have a dependency on S.
- Implementing annotation processing in Java 5 is absolutely not the same thing as in Java 6.
- Java 5 relies on a separate execution of apt. The corresponding tutorials [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) and [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html) help understanding the basics of annotation processing and implementation in Java 5. Good reading for newbies.
- Implementing annotation processing in Java 5 *with Maven* is tricky. One needs to add a local dependency to `tools.jar` to access the API described in these tutorials. Not clean. Some third-party plugins calling the apt are available, but not well documented.
- Those using Java 6 should **not** jump-start implementing their processors according to the above tutorials.

**Annotation Processing in Java 6 with Maven**

- A new [package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html#package_description) has been delivered in Java 6 to process annotations: the [Pluggable Annotation Processing](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/14-java-60-features-part-2-pluggable-annotation-proce-1.html).
- To implement a processor, create a separate Maven project. The above tutorial or [this](http://www.zdnet.com/article/writing-and-processing-custom-annotations-part-3/) one explains how to proceed. This is our library S.
- Then, create your project P and add a Maven dependency on S.
- There is currently an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975298/generated-code-not-taken-into-account-in-maven-compile-process) with the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html), but a workaround is available [here](http://relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateStaticMetamodelGeneratorAnnotationProcessor). Use it to compile your generated code as part of existing annotated code.

**...and code generation**

- A great Java code generation library called [CodeModel](http://codemodel.java.net/) is available from Maven central. A good tutorial is available [here](http://namanmehta.blogspot.com/2010/01/use-codemodel-to-generate-java-source.html). The javax annotation processing package offers some tools to generate output too.

Comment: There is a lot of good stuff in this answer. But one thing is NOT true: you can do it in one maven pass. Here is an example that also includes an annotation processor using JCodeModel: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/example-maven-project-setups/tree/master/compile-time-annotation-processing

Comment: @user1050755 Thanks for a great suggestion. One question: why did you use that JCodeModel and not the official one? https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-codemodel

Answer (score 4):

maven-processor-plugin can do that...

https://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/

Example from documentation:

```
<build> <plugins>
  <!-- Run annotation processors on src/main/java sources -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <!-- Disable annotation processors during normal compilation -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins> </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Maven-Antlr-Plugin exactly does this. It generates Java classes from a grammar and the compile plugin compiles the generated classes. May it might be usefull the [maven-annotation-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks, but honestly I think maven-antlr-plugin is overkill. Moreover, the site does not provide a complete example explaining how to solve the issue I raise. I am thinking more about something along the AnnotationProcessor.The maven-annotation-plugin looks interesting, but it is work-in-progress with incomplete documentation. Not helpful.

Comment: I don't think he was advocating **using** the antlr plugin directly, but looking at its source to see how it does what it does.