# Maven can't found custom annotation processor

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I have written simple annotation processor and trying to run it in current project. My pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>
                            com.company.AnCheck
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But error message is:

```
[ERROR] Annotation processor 'com.company.AnCheck' not found
```

I also have added it into META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor

```
com.company.AnCheck
```

Annotation processor extends AbstractProcessor and exists in the same project in com.company package.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to build a seprate library containing your annotation processor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967514/maven-example-of-annotation-preprocessing-and-generation-of-classes-in-same-comp which might be a duplicate

Comment: @cghislai you are right, thx.